# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Name is blank while setting body params

Tags: java, rest, http, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following example of a POST request to some system.

The request looks like this:

[image]

I've tried to implement it with the following method:

```
/**
     * This method creates a HTTP POST/PUT/PATCH request and fills body
     * with data from Map
     * @param urlToPrepareRequest URL for a request
     * @param keyValueToPutInBodyRequest Map of entities to put in body request
     * @param httpMethod HTTP method (POST, PUT, PATCH are available)
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if httpMethod is wrong
     * @return ready HTTP POST/PUT/PATCH with filled body
    */
    public static HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase createHttpRequestAndFillBody(String urlToPrepareRequest, Map<String, Object> keyValueToPutInBodyRequest, String httpMethod) 
{
    HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase httpRequest;

    if (httpMethod.equals("POST")) 
    {
        httpRequest = new HttpPost(urlToPrepareRequest);
    }
    else if (httpMethod.equals("PUT")) 
    {
        httpRequest = new HttpPut(urlToPrepareRequest);
    }
    else if (httpMethod.equals("PATCH")) 
    {
        httpRequest = new HttpPatch(urlToPrepareRequest);
    }
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP method can't be used " + httpMethod + " available values are \"POST\", \"PUT\", \"PATCH\"");

    Iterator it = keyValueToPutInBodyRequest.entrySet().iterator();

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

    while (it.hasNext()) 
    {   
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();

        String keyOfBodyToPut = (String) pair.getKey();
        Object valueOfBodyToPut = pair.getValue();

        if(!(valueOfBodyToPut instanceof byte[])) 
        {
            builder.addTextBody(keyOfBodyToPut, valueOfBodyToPut.toString());
        }
        else 
        {
            builder.addBinaryBody(keyOfBodyToPut, (byte[]) valueOfBodyToPut);
        }
    } 

    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    httpRequest.setEntity(entity);

    return httpRequest;
}
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Name is blank
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.notBlank(Asserts.java:64)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPartBuilder.build(FormBodyPartBuilder.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addPart(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:168)
```

It's all because inside a map there's the following code:

```
bodyParams.put("", currentChunk);
```

`currentChunk` is of type `byte []`. At first, I thought that it's possible to put an empty key inside a body request (because on the screen above there's no key), but now it made me think that perhaps it's not.

What's the problem?

And how do I make my method to be more inline with the request from Postman?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the exact some error message. Did you find the problem?

Comment: Well, it turned out that you cannot set a body param wihout a name. I tracked down the package sent to the server using wireshark. My solution was to set the name equals to "file". Try using wireshark for that or text me if you need help